# Spring boot not able to inject HashiCorp Vault array values

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

i was working on springboot and using HashiCorp Vault

in vault i stored two values in form of json

```json
{
  "singleValue": "single value",
  "value_arr": ["value1","value2","value3"]
}
```

in spring boot

i am able to load the property of singleValue

```java
@Value("${singleValue}")
private String value;
```

but i am not able to load the value_arr

```java
@Value("${value_arr}")
private String[] value;
```

i have even tried

```java
@Value("${value_arr}")
private List<String> value;
```

but nothing is working when i tried to load the value_arr in spring boot. Is there any way to load the array values from HashiCorp Vault

i was expecting that value array or value list should load the values which has been mentioned in value_arr of the vault

Comment: based on what it says in [spring-vault - Object to Vault JSON Mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/docs/current/reference/html/#vault.repositories.mapping), with `List<String>` should work fine. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? show some config, log error messages. Also you could try to enable set your logs to `DEBUG` level and see if you find something

Comment: It is mentioning that it is unable to find the placeholder in logs for value_arr